# A good textbook about value at risk in R?

Tags: risk, business-intelligence

I am so new to business applications and interested in learning about value at risk. My question is, could you please recommend for me a nice/easy book about value at risk with applications using the R program?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found that this textbook is clearly written and easy to understand. Value at Risk is addressed in Chapter 19, "Risk."

David Ruppert & David S. Matteson. *Statistics and Data Analysis for Financial Engineering with R examples*. 2nd Ed. Springer (2015).

Comment: Thanks. It is really a good one.